# extend ruby on rails activerecord from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems

I have an idea to write a gem but I don't have enough experience in extending ruby on rails.

So here is what I want

For example here is a model file

```
class Modelname < ActiveRecord::Base
    methodname :columnname
end
```

So what "methodname" does is that it activates hook before db create/update and modifies "columnname" text

Answer (score 2):

How is this different to

```
Object.update_attribute( :columnname, "value" )
```

Or a before_filter that calls a method with the above behaviour?

Comment: Yeah but I want everything in a ruby gem not with a chunk of code for copy pasting